# Are "where to watch/read/buy" questions on topic, and if not, shouldn't that be mentioned in the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, scope

A couple of hours ago I was the first to flag ["What is the availability of full episodes of the Shannara Chronicles on the MTV website for non-MTV subscribers?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114865/what-is-the-availability-of-full-episodes-of-the-shannara-chronicles-on-the-mtv) as off-topic.

However, afterwards I discovered that I couldn't find any rule that explicitly prohibits these kind of questions, unlike over at the Movies SE where ["Locating or purchasing Movies or TV content" is listed as off-topic](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Granted, neither is this topic listed as one of [SF&F's allowed topics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); and considering that this question was quickly closed others agree that it wasn't an appropriate subject.

However, perhaps this subject should be listed either [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) or [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: see: [Are shopping questions on topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/499/5184)

Comment: @phantom42 Ah, I hadn't searched for "shopping". Thanks for the link.

Comment: I don't think the first help center link can be customized. That's just a standard page each site has.

Comment: The general rule of thumb is "*If you've tried everywhere sensible, then looked a bit harder, then tried a bunch of other places and you can't find anywhere to buy it, then tried some more*", **then** (and only then) may you ask the question. Oh, and expect it to get buried in downvotes.